# Why do people say that blue light is damaging to the eyes?

Tags: vision, light

It's easy to find claims that blue light (e.g., from computer screens) is damaging to the eyes. For example, [here](https://www.visioncenter.org/blog/blue-light-effects-eyes/) is some discussion of the topic. Is there any physical mechanism by which blue (not violet or UV) can damage eyes?

Comment: Not an answer, but I can't help but notice that that's a commercial concern which sells blue-light blocking wearables.

Comment: At the bottom of the article are links to the relevant research article.